# Do sugar alcohols cause cancer according to the latest research?

Tags: cancer, sugar, liver, sweeteners

According to this [Upstate article](https://www.upstate.edu/news/articles/2023/2023-03-25-perl.php), [recent research](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42255-022-00711-9) has shown that there is a link between ingredients in sweeteners (sugar alcohols) and liver cancer. One of the coauthors has made several strong statements:

> “We should avoid using sugar alcohols, such as erythritol and
> sorbitol, as sweeteners.”

and also:

> It’s causing liver cancer, there’s no doubt. When we treat cancer
> cells with sweeteners, it causes the proliferation of cancer cells;
> they grow much more rapidly. In contrast, when we treat cancer cells
> with inhibitors of aldose reductase, it blocks their proliferation.

I would like to know if the performed research indeed points to this relationship, as the statements seem to be very strong.

Comment: Yes, it points to it, but since the research is limited, it's animal-based and in vitro only, it's not strong evidence. In your second quote, he's referring to in vitro studies, and just because sweeteners affect the growth of cancer cells in a petri dish doesn't mean they do in the human body. Ditto with mice.

Comment: OK, but I am more concerned about the first quote. Hasn't a similar phenomenon been observed with sugar (which also causes the proliferation of cancer cells)? Yet, despite this, the consensus is that sugar does not cause cancer. Does this study imply that one should be more concerned when consuming sugar alcohols compared to sugar? (https://www.dana-farber.org/for-patients-and-families/care-and-treatment/support-services-and-amenities/nutrition-services/faqs/sugar-and-cancer/)

Comment: From the link you just provided: _To date, there are no randomized controlled trials showing sugar causes cancer._ There's your answer. We don't know.

Comment: OK, but taking everything mentioned into account, does it make rational sense to prefer sugar over sugar alcohols when it comes to reducing the risk of cancer?

Comment: I don't know. Nutrition research is always a sort of quagmire of conflicting results. That's one of the reasons nutrition questions are off topic here unless they're directly related to medical treatment. Your question squeaks by because it's primarily about cancer risk rather than nutrition.